# Make a flexbox container with wrapped items scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, overflow

I have a grid of images that are spaced into columns dynamically using `flex-wrap: wrap`. However there is one problem, I don't know how to make the container scrollable because it has a dynamic height. I have searched for solutions to this problem but I don't really know how to adapt them for my use case.

This is my code:

```css
.imagegrid {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.image {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to make either the image-container or imagegrid scrollable on the y-axis.

This is the HTML, if needed:

```html
<div class="imagegrid">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src="image"/>
    <img class="image" src="image2"/>
    (multiple images)
  </div>
</div>

The images are added dynamically from a database. I do not know what the height of the container will be.
```

Comment: You cannot have a vertically scrolling container if it has a dynamic height, it will always expand to fit its content, only explicit height containers can scroll vertically

Comment: When you apply 100% height, if it's in the body that has a height of auto, (auto means use as much space as you need) - 100% of as much space as you need is as much space as you need, and therefore it isn't really an explicit height

Comment: So you want your container to scroll, but don't know what the height of it will be, well if it scrolls you don't need to know what the height will be.... cuz it's gon scroll

Comment: You can do a max-height of whatever height you want it to cap out at if there are too few images if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1):

In order for elements to scroll vertically you must do 2 things

- Give them an explicit height that makes them have to scroll
- Give them an overflow setting of auto or scroll

I've added a working example with both applied:

```css
.imagegrid {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: var(--background);
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.image {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 270px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagegrid">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" />
    <img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/250x250" /> (multiple images)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the images are added dynamically from a database so I don't know what the height of the container will be.

Comment: @Tenpi Please add this information in your question so I am able to provide a better answer